# PSNR-based classification & subimage-based classification

Tags: classification

*PSNR, is an engineering term for the ratio between the maximum possible power of a signal and the power of corrupting noise that affects the fidelity of its representation. PSNR is most commonly used to measure the quality of reconstruction of lossy compression codecs (e.g., for image compression).*

But whats **" PSNR-based classification "?** also whats **"subimage-based classification "?** and how can we apply it to measure the performance of images comparison? there are any functions in MATlab for those technique ?

Any information gonna help a lot, thanks.